# How to get Create React App production build to polyfill String.isWellFormed() or Array.findLast() for supported browsers

Tags: reactjs, cross-browser, create-react-app

Create React App production build seems to not polyfill String.isWellFormed() for safari 14.1 and Firefox 119 which are supported browsers according to npx browserslist.

I created a new create react app using `npx create-react-app my-app`
which in the `package.json` has the following

```
 ...
 "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    ...
```

then I added the following code to src/App.js

```
  const strings = ["ab\uD800", "abc"];
  for (const str of strings) {
    console.log(str.isWellFormed());
  }
```

then I built for production
`npm run build`
and ran using serve
`serve -d build`
and the compiled code still included `.isWellFormed(` and thus in the console we got the error
`TypeError: n.isWellFormed is not a function`

`String.isWellFormed()` is supported as of Safari `16.4` (and Firefox `119`)
But `npx browserslist`
shows that we should be supporting Safari `14.1` (and Firefox `115`) as well so it should inject polyfill code

I was able to test this on firefox using their previous version downloads (though one must be careful not to allow firefox to update before the test occurs) https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/116.0/

In addition I saw the same lack of polyfill with `Array.findLast()` function (which is supported as of Safari `15.4` and thus needs polyfill for Safari `14.1`)